# Asp.Net Hosting and file write permissions

Tags: hosting, asp.net

Apologies if this isn't the right place for this question but...

**With shared hosting providers e.g. http://www.discountasp.net/ will my Asp.Net web application have permissions to write/create text (xml) files within the web root?**

Comment: Seems like a question you should be asking the hosting provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some hosts let you create/editing files, some others not, instead, they provide a file manager which lets you set the permissions. Though it's better to ask your host about it.

Answer (score 2):

Your asp.net web app should be able to.

http://community.discountasp.net/showthread.php?t=8322&highlight=write+files

Answer (score 0):

Just look for a provider that allows you to change folder permissions. [My provider](http://www.reliablesite.net) allows me to do it right through the file manager.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible with most of the hosts. I am using DotNetPanel on my VPS' and it does allow it. My host also provides DotNetPanel shared plans and they do allow this as well.